# How to Commit Mp3 Files to Folders in Gitlab through API

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, gitlab-api

I am trying to commit a file to Gitlab through the API.

The code had been working for over 6 months but now has stopped working, nothing in the code had changed. The file is commited to Gitlab, however it is corrupted.

I have went through the Guzzle documentation and everything looks correct, and I have done the same for the Gitlab documentation about commits.

I am now using the Laravel Illuminate/Http class to send the commits but the same thing is still happening. I am able to commit to Gitlab, but the file is not formatted correctly.

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
    'PRIVATE-TOKEN' => $gitlab_token,
])
    ->post('https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/.../repository/commits/', [
        'branch' => 'test-branch',
        'commit_message' => 'Updated audio file test.mp3',
        'actions' => array(array(
            'action' => 'update',
            'file_path' => 'filePath/../.mp3',
            'content' => base64_encode($var)
        )),
    ]);
```

If I do not encode the contents of the file to base 64 I get the error:

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded in file

Has anything changed on the API side that has effected how files are processed for committing? Has anyone else found a solution?

Comment: I don't use Guzzle or this API, but that doesn't look like a proper API post to me. You've got an extra array, is that intentional? You're also not specifying a content type header. Is this supposed to be `x-www-url-encoded`? Doesn't seem like it should be.

Comment: @miken32 The double array is intentional because the Gitlab API expects that information in it's own array. I did try the content-type in the header like you suggested, and I get the response "unsupported media type", if I don't put that content-type header it commits successfully with the wrong format. thank you for your suggestion, I now have some direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two problems; first there's no content type specified. The post request will be sent just as `multipart/form-data` with a file attachment, or `application/x-www-url-encoded` without. This API is expecting JSON data.

Second, there is a parameter in the [commit endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html) to specify file encoding. It defaults to "text" but you are sending a base64-encoded file.

I'm not familiar enough with the Gitlab API to say for sure, but your `file_path` property looks strange as well; shouldn't it just be ".mp3" to be put into that directory?

Try this:

```php
$response = Http::withHeaders([
    'PRIVATE-TOKEN' => $gitlab_token,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
])
    ->post('https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/.../repository/commits/', [
        'branch' => 'test-branch',
        'commit_message' => 'Updated audio file test.mp3',
        'actions' => [
            [
                'action' => 'update',
                'file_path' => '.mp3',
                'content' => base64_encode($var),
                'encoding' => 'base64',
            ]
        ],
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you have saved the day. the problem was the combination of the 'Content-Type parameter and the 'encoding' parameter you suggested.